# How to use multiprocessing or threading with tkinter

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am trying to make a simple space invaders game and a problem I have run into is getting things t happen at the same time. I have binded the shooting action to the canvas of the game so that when you click a function is called. I would like it so that this function can be called multiple times at once so that multiple "lasers/bullets" can be seen on the screen at any one time. At the minute when you click and a "laser/bullet" is already on screen, the previous one disappears and a new one appears. CODE:

```
class Game1():

def __init__(self, xcoord1=380, ycoord1=550, xcoord2=400, ycoord2=570):
    self.Master = Master
    self.Master.geometry("800x600+300+150")
    Game1Canvas = Canvas(self.Master, bg="black", height=600, width=800)
    Game1Canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
    self.Canvas = Game1Canvas
    self.Canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.Shoot)
    self.Ship = self.Canvas.create_rectangle(self.xcoord1, self.ycoord1, self.xcoord2, self.ycoord2, fill = "red")

def Shoot(self):
    self.LaserLocation = 0
    for self.LaserLocation in range(0 , 112):
        Master.after(1, self.Canvas.create_rectangle(self.xcoord1, self.ycoord1 - (self.LaserLocation * 5), self.xcoord2 - 5, self.ycoord2 - (self.LaserLocation * 5), fill = "pink", tag=str(CurrentTag)))
        Master.update()
        self.Canvas.delete(str(CurrentTag))
```

This is a much more "dumbed" down version of the code at the minute because I've been trying a bunch of different ways to get this working and it's a mess. I am aware of the multiprocessing and threading imports and I have tried them both but am unable to get them working for my code. If someone could reply back with a solution I would be very grateful. Cheers.

Comment: This is something that really does not need threading... You should just keep track of all 'bullets' on the Canvas and draw those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use multithreading or multiprocessing. You also don't need (nor want) to be drawing new rectangles every millisecond, or multiple times per millisecond.

The solution is to have your `Shoot` function merely create a single rectangle, and add it to a list. Then, using a simple animation mechanism, iterate over the list and move each bullet up one or two pixels. You do this by creating a function that calls itself every 20-30 ms.

The solution looks something like this:

```
def Shoot(self):
    laser = self.Canvas.create_rectangle(...)
    self.lasers.append(laser)

def do_animation(self):
    # make a copy of the list of lasers to iterate
    # over, so we can remove items from the original
    # list when they go off screen
    lasers = self.lasers[:]
    for laser in lasers:
        # get current coordinates of this laser
        (x0,y0,x1,y1) = self.canvas.bbox(laser)

        if x1 < self.canvas.winfo_height():
            # if it is not off screen, move it up
            self.canvas.move(laser, 0, -10)
        else:
            # if it IS off screen, delete it
            self.canvas.delete(laser)
            self.lasers.remove(laser)

    self.after(30, self.do_animation)
```

The above will move the lasers every 30 milliseconds (about 33 fps).

Comment: OK i'm a noob at this and i'm struggling to understand how that would solve the problem of multiple lasers running across the screen at once. If the do_animation function is being run for one laser then how will others be moving as well? Or is that something to do with the "for laser in self.lasers" line as I don't quite get what that would do? As a side note, for actually animating it what would you suggest the best method would be? Am I right in thinking deleting it and moving it upward is good or is there a more efficient method I have not heard of? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Oh Ok never mind I understand what you've done now, however if you could give me pointers for a good way to animate the rectangles that would be great. Cheers.

Comment: @ElliotHoward: I've updated my answer to include a more complete example.